# getting unexpected result in acosh() in ios

Tags: ios, macros

My code is as Follows 
`NSLog(@"result=%f",acosh([@"30.0" doubleValue]* M_PI / 180));`

and result is coming
 `result=nan`

where M_PI is pre-defined macro in x-code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

30 * pi / 180 < 1.

According to the acosh docs (for example here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/acosh.3.html, iOS docs state the same)
for arguments < 1 acosh returns NaN.

If you check for the actual value of acosh for your argument: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acosh%28pi+*+30.0+%2F+180%29](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=acosh%28pi%20*%2030.0%20%2F%20180%29) you'll see that it's a complex number (imaginary one actually).